# Multiply function-valued matrices

Tags: functions, matrix, operators

I would like to create a notebook for calculations in supersymmetric quantum mechanics. The basic building blocks are two functions (or maybe better: operators):

```
A := (W[#1] #2 + D[#2, #1]) &;
B := (W[#1] #2 -D[#2, #1]) &;
```

With these definitions you can apply these operators to a pair of a variable `x` and a function `f[x]` like `A[x,f[x]]` and one obtains `f[x] W[x] + Derivative[1][f][x]`.

Now, these functions `A` and `B` are embedded into matrices:

```
Q1 := ({{0, 0}, {A[#1, #2], 0}}) &;
Q2 := ({{0, B[#1, #2]}, {0, 0}}) &;
```

Again, it is possible to apply these matrices to a variable `x` and a function `f[x]` like `Q[x,f[x]]` and one obtains

```
{{0, 0}, {f[x] W[x] + Derivative[1][f][x], 0}}
```

or in traditional form
[image]

I wonder, if there is a possibility to multiply the matrices `Q1` and `Q2` in such a way that the result is again a function that expects the two arguments `[x,f[x]].`

The trouble is, that the internal matrix operations have to distinguish between multiplication and addition of ordinary numbers and functions. I succeeded to implement addition and multiplication that is sensitive to the nature of the operands on the level of `A` and `B`,eg.

```
mul[a_, b_] := If[NumberQ[a] && NumberQ[b], a*b,
If[NumberQ[a], Through[a*b[#1, #2], 0] &,
If[NumberQ[b], Through[b*a[#1, #2], 0] &,
 a[#1, b[#1, #2]] &
]]];
```

and

```
add[a_, b_] :=If[NumberQ[a] && NumberQ[b], a + b,
 If[NumberQ[a], a + b[#1, #2] &,
  If[NumberQ[b], b + a[#1, #2] &,
   Through[a[#1, #2] + b[#1, #2], 0] &]]]
]];
```

I have no idea, how to deal with the matrix multiplication. For instance, how can I get the (2,1) component of Q as a function. If I write `Q[[1,2,1]]`, I get `#2 W[#1]` but I would need `W[#1] #2 + D[#2,#1]&`?

Comment: `A = W[#1] #2 + HoldForm@D[#2, #1] & ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a generalized matrix product, then `Inner` will do the trick. This snippet performs a matrix product, where multiplication is replaced with `mul` and addition with `add`:

```
Inner[mul,{{a,b},{c,d}},{{w,x},{y,z}},add]
```

However, Q1 and Q2 are written as functions, rather than matrices with function-valued elements. Using them as written, the matrix product would be implemented like this:

```
Q = Q1[#1,#2].Q2[#1,#2]&
```

Then a particular component could be reached with `Q[#1,#2][[row,col]]&`.

Comment: Thank you so far, but I need the combination of both ideas. `Q1[#1,#2].Q2[#1,#2]&` works fine, however, it just multiplies the functions of the components of the matrices. In the customized `mul`, the functions are composed `A[#1,A[#1,#2]]&`. So, I tried `Mmul[a_,b_]:=Inner[mul,a[#1,#2],b[#1,#2],add]&`, which doesn't work however.

Comment: Also, just `Mmul[a_, b_] :=Inner[mul, a, b, add] ` does not work. What is the correct syntax for this situation?

Comment: The reason `Inner` won't work is because Q isn't actually a matrix. Q[x,f[x]] is a matrix with numeric elements. If you define them like `Q1 := ({{0, 0}, {A, 0}})`, then `Inner` will work.

Comment: Fine, this works. Now I can access elements of `Q=Inner[mul,Q1,Q2,Plus]` via `Through[Q[[2, 2]][x, f[x]]]` for example. Is there a way to perform this for the full matrix in one step? Just `Through[Q[x,f[x]]]` doesn't work, since the matrix itself is not a function now but only its components.

Comment: You can use `Map[#[x,f]&, Q, {2}]` to call the function for each cell of the matrix.